# Can hearing aids damage the ears of those with profound hearing loss because they must exceed 85 dB?

Tags: hearing, hearing-aids, hearing-loss

By definition, profound hearing loss means their hearing threshold is over 90 dB. If the 85 dB rule still applies, in theory, hearing aids can damage their residual hearing.

There are hearing aids designed for those with profound hearing loss. The most powerful one so far as claimed has a maximum output of 146 dB SPL but we're taught that immediate hearing loss can happen around 120 dB.
https://www.oticon.com/professionals/brainhearing-technology/xceed-technology

With the need to wear hearing aids all day, wouldn't it be easy for them to damage their residual hearing?

Overall, the reviewers seemed satisfied with the Xceed, based on a quick online search. There must be some kind of mechanism protecting their surviving hair cells from the extreme sound levels coming from the product.